# Matlab: Execute the loop until the specified conditions are met

Tags: matlab, while-loop, simulink

Recently came across a simple issues that I could not solve on my own. I have a Simulink model that uses a matlab function for some calculations inside the model. The idea is that at some specified moment of time I need to change the voltage of an electric drive. And I need to change it until the rotor’s position reaches another specified value. For instance:

```
 If control_signal == 1;  (command to start the execution);    
 While Angle ~= 180 \\ desired angle is 180;
  Control voltage = 5 - 0.1 (5V is the initial value, while the increment of 
         the voltage change is 0.1)
  End
  end
```

So technically what I was thinking will happen, is that the cycle will be executed until the angle of 180 is reached, at some value of the control voltage (for instance 4.6). But when I am running this code, Simulink can’t execute the model. So without any warning or errors, simulation freezes at some stage (when the main condition kicks in). So looks like it can’t process further when the cycle’s execution starts. Can somebody help me with the code? Because the described behaviour of the model during simulation is definitely caused by the above mentioned code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the angle is being updated in the right direction, and will in fact converge to 180 degrees (i.e. and not ever skip past it)?

Comment: You can try to debug your code and check how the angle changes during the simulation.

Comment: @infromation, sure it will. I can calculate it, can use oprimization toolbox to estimate the corresponded voltage. But what I am trying to do now is to put the same process in the model's function.

Comment: @m7913d, thanks. That's how coding works in general. I know the physics of the process, but if you read again "So without any warning or errors, simulation freezes at some stage (when the main condition kicks in)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you convert the value of the angle expressed in radians to degrees, and you calculate the angle beforehand using trigonometry functions - it will never reach precisely 180 degrees. You should choose some epsilon such that `180 - epsilon` is **close enough** to 180 for your application and use that value as your loop condition.

Also, based on your description of the problem you are trying to solve, sounds like you actually want to check whether the angle is not greater than 180, not if it equals 180.

Also, you are incrementing your voltage incorrectly. Everytime you enter the loop, your control_voltage variable equals 5 - 0.1, which means it's constant and will equal 4.9 no matter how many times you run that loop. This is the correct way:

```
control_voltage = 5; % initial value
if control_signal == 1;  (command to start the execution);
    while Angle ~= (180 - epsilon) % some epsilon of your choice
        control_voltage = control_voltage - 0.1; % now it's smaller by 0.1 every time the loop is run
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @KjMag. Well, it's a good guess, but still does not work. In my case, I want to abort that cycle when I reach 180 degrees. But I've realised that I made a mistake, re-writing and putting here the code. It should be "Control voltage = control voltage - 0.1". When the "control voltage" is specified before the cycle. So in this case I will update the value of the voltage after every iteration. Or I am wrong? In any case, it still behaves like I've described above. Thank you if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: If you want people to be able to help you further, you need to be more detailed about what you mean when you say it doesn't work. Try to investigate what values you are getting instead of the ones you are expecting and update your question with these details.

Comment: did not get it. I can't check the values during the execution because "So without any warning or errors, simulation freezes at some stage (when the main condition kicks in). So looks like it can’t process further when the cycle’s execution starts", As it was mentioned in the question from the beginning. If I could troubleshoot it in this way, I would not post any questions here.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you can just stop the Matlab script anytime and see at which line it's stuck. You don't have to wait until it finishes. Also, see my updated answer as I've spotted another mistake in your code.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the code (my first comment), Well, other bits of the code in this function were written by me, and now It's stuck after putting this loop with the control voltage. So, this is definitely the only issue now. And since the execution freezes, I just simply can't wait until it finishes. Otherwise, yeah, I could check the system's behaviour and change the code accordingly. I've tried the updated code, and it still freezes. I was thinking about other ways of implementing my idea, but looks like this is the simplest and the most straightforward solution. That does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other: you know that if the program freezes, it's enough to press the Pause button in Matlab, and then you can see the state of the program, right? It's not a problem even if it's stuck inside an infinite loop. You can then just debug the program step by step and see how the value changes. Without it and/or possibly other relevant code (the one that calculates the angle) it's impossible to help you. Also, post your real code, because what you've written so far is not a valid Matlab code.

Comment: Ok, when I am saying the code freezes, it literally means to the extend that the Pause button does not help. It shows the status Pausing, nothing more. The only way I can make the software accessible again, use Ctrl-C to abort the execution. Hence, by using standard debugging tools I can't work through the whole code either.  The angle calculations are taking place in the Simulink model, not a Matlab code, so I don't think it will be any useful for you.

Comment: Moreover, I am under a few IP agreements, so the model/code can't be posted here. If the code in general makes sense, I will work through the model itself, to find any possible conflicts. Thank you for your time.